# If I install linux to a USB thumb drive, would it become a live USB?

Tags: opensuse, live-usb

I need a live USB that functions like normal install, with the ability like install app, add/remove user account etc... the guide on the internet which I have found require me a Live CD, but the linux distribution which I am interest in(opensuse) did not provide it, so, what should I do?

Comment: Well, a live USB typically refers to one that can be used to test the environment and install it if the user finds it satisfactory. In this case, it sounds like you simply want a bootable USB drive (which, admittedly, is similar). Many distributions show you how to accomplish this in their docs, but the general rule is that it isn't *drastically* different from a standard installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All my USB's are 'normal' installs. If you have an install CD/DVD you should be able to install to your USB stick or USB HDD no problem. If you have installed to a regular HDD you should be able to clone that over to the USB too, which is what I do since I use the USB's as backups.